# HTTP 500 Internal Server Error using all APIs on Bluemix Apiconnect

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, http-status-code-500, apiconnect

Since yesterday, creating new loopback api (hello-world or notes) and pushing on Bluemix Apiconnect, they give an error at invoke. hello-world: /Messages/greet and notes: /Notes

```
{ "httpCode": "500", "httpMessage": "Internal Server Error", "moreInformation": "Internal Server Error" }
```

Locally (on apic edit) everything works fine.

Why default example (hello-world and notes, without customs) api stopped working even (on bluemix)? Bluemix broke?

Comment: Which Bluemix region are you connecting to? There was an access issue in the EU-GB region earlier today, but it has been resolved. For connectivity status, you can always check http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus.

Comment: US South region

Comment: Okay, so that's not the issue. I've alerted the API Connect development team to your question.

Answer (score 1):

@alexdeia,

The error is a generic error indicating the gateway failed to process the request.  This might just be a hiccup.  Are you still seeing the error?  Thanks and best regards,
Peter

Comment: In example (starter) api yes.

If using gatewayscript (without Invoke at Assemble), api works.

Comment: The starter example API is used in conjunction with publishing the loopback application to Bluemix.  Can you examine your Bluemix org/space for the application you published and ensure that the route create for the application has a check mark.  The check mark means the route is secured.  The route will resemble https://apiconnect-xxxxxx.yyyyy.apic.mybluemix.net.